How do i see usage metrics report for a Power BI Semantic Model?
[
In the PBI docs, it says if you click on the 3 dots, you will be able to see the option of "Usage Metrics Report" but unfortunately I can't see Usage Metrics Report for my semantic model.
More context: The semantic model is hosted on "My workspace" and i have a PBI pro license

The article describes how to get stats for the reports, not semantic models. So you need to create a report from that model first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-datasets-discover-across-workspaces
There might be something that could be done on a semantic model side. What is your end goal: what exactly and why were you hoping to see in a usage metric report?

Oh hey, @Andrii! Thanks for your reply! So one quick thing is : i'm not able to see that option even for reports that i've created.
so i have an excel sheet connected to my semantic model which business users are running queries on. i wanted to know how many users or queries are hitting my semantic model and present a user adoption percentage to leadership...

I see. Do you know how do your users run queries (i.e. do they run notebooks, or build reports using the model, etc)? As for you not seeing the Usage Metrics option for the reports, do you have edit access to those reports?

hey @Andrii, yes i do have edit access for those report.
the users run queries mostly on excel (by connecting excel to the pbi dataset)

In my poor experience, that mentioned usage metrics report is only avalible for reports and the semantic models are not. However, you can use the semantic model (created by Power BI) that is used to build thar usage metrics report. You only need to create a new power bi file(using power bi desktop) and conect by powerbi datasets. than you search "usage metrics" and it will be there..
